# Oflline MAP Fully disconnected

Tags: arcgis-desktop, qt

My desktop app contains a Map using ArcGIS runtime SDK. The app should work in a fully disconnected environment. The app will be installed on a Glider (Aircraft).
I have done all the app on Qt and the map provided via ArcGIS-Server using `Map`, `MapGraphicsView` Classes.

I found an example `LocalServerFeatureLayer` but this is also not working when I am disconnected only (map didn't show)  when connected (the map start working ).
So my question: Is there is a way to get the map of a country downloaded offline and installed into a local server on the same pc that contains the my app. If it is available what is the process to do that.

I am using Qt-C++ , SDK-100.8